# Python : How to use speech_recognition or other modules to convert base64 audio string to text?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, base64, speech-recognition

I have base64 audio string like `data:audio/mpeg;base64,//OAxAAAAANIAAAAABhqZ3f4StN3gOAaB4NAUBYZLv......`, and I was trying to convert the base64 to wav file using base64 module in Python:

```py
    decode_bytes = base64.b64decode(encoding_str)
    with open(file_name + '.wav', "wb") as wav_file:
        wav_file.write(decode_bytes)
```

Then I was trying to convert the audio to text using speech_recognition module, and it gives error below:

```
ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your audio file is mp3 from mime-type - `audio/mpeg`. You will need to save it as mp3

```
decode_bytes = base64.b64decode(encoding_str)
    with open(file_name + '.mp3', "wb") as wav_file:
        wav_file.write(decode_bytes)
```

And convert the mp3 to wav format either using [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) or FFmpeg and then give this wav file to speech_recognition module.